# Equivalent definitions of regular categories?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

maybe this is a stupid question, but I could not solve it after some time of meditation.

There are four different notions of regular categories:

1) A cartesian category with coequalizers of kernel pairs, where regulars epimorphisms (coequalizers of some parallel arrows) are stable under pullbacks;

2) A cartesian category with images, where extremal epimorphisms (covers http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extremal+epimorphism) are stable under pullback

3) A cartesian category with coequalizers, where regular epimorphisms are stable under pullbacks.

4) A category with images, where $g^{*} (\text{Im}f) \cong \text{Im}(g^{*}f)$ holds.

In Johnstone's elephant book ,it's asserted that 2 is equivalent to 4 and it's proved that 3 is equivalent to 2 + "existence of coequalizers". But in http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+category it's asserted that 1 is equivalent to 4 + "cartesianness" and it seems very strange. I doubt this is really true if Johnstone's assertion is true. So the question are:

**Is 1 equivalent to 2?**

**Is 2 equivalent to 4?**

**Is 1 equivalent to 4 + "cartesianness"?**

**Is 1 equivalent to 3?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (3) is stronger than the others because coequalisers don't have to exist in general. (4) is weaker than the others because finite limits don't have to exist in general.

Comment: @ZhenLin What about 1 and 2. Any ideas? Of course, every regular is extremal and, under definition 2, they're equal, but, in definition 1, I don't see if they're equal...

Comment: (1) and (2) are equivalent. Every extremal epi is regular: take its (regular epi, mono)-factorisation and observe that the monomorphism part must be an isomorphism.

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh, you're right. Any ideas about 1 and 4 + "cartesianess"? You may want to repost your commentary as an answer...

Comment: Well, isn't (2) just a way of making (4) + cartesian precise?

Comment: @ZhenLin You mean because every extremal epi is of the kind $\text{dom}f \rightarrow \text{dom (im} f)$. Yes, in this case it holds one implication from  4 + "cartesianness" to 2 and, hence to 1. The problem is the other direction (when trying to prove the minimality of the pullback of the image I get an arrow in an opposite direction).

Comment: Strange, I think that the obvious direction is that (2) implies (4). At least if you go via (1).

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok,let me elaborate it better. Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g: A' \rightarrow B$. Now given a subobject $D$ of $A'$ that factors through $g^{*} A \rightarrow A'$ how do you get an arrow $g^{*} \text{Im} (f) \rightarrow D$? A natural way is to use $D \rightarrow g^{*}\exists_g D $ but the arrow that I get is in the opposite direction, so I cannot compose it with $g^{*} \text{Im} (f)\rightarrow g^{*} \exists_g D$...

Comment: It's very simple: under (1) or (2), the pullback of a regular/extremal epimorphism is regular/extremal, so (regular/extremal epi, mono)-factorisations are preserved by pullback, hence images are preserved by pullback.

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh! Of course, it was simpler than I thought. Thanks!