# Definition of a regular category via extremal epi

Tags: category-theory

I know one definition of a regular category saying that a category is regular if it is finitely complete, every kernel pair admits a coequalizer and regular epis are stable under pullback. Now, I am trying to find **the definition in terms of extremal epis**, but in Borceux's Handbook of categorical algebra I can only find one in terms of strong epis. He proves the equivalence of strong and regular epis in a regular category with respect to the first definition above, and further that the definition can be stated in terms of strong epis. But no mention of extremal epis. I read that extremal epis coincide with regular epis in a regular category, but can't find the proof of this. Is it obvious somehow? Any pointers?

Note: I found this related question but no clear answer [Equivalent definitions of regular categories?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030490/equivalent-definitions-of-regular-categories), at least for me

Comment: Look in the section on regular categories in _Sketches of an elephant_.

Comment: @ZhenLin He says that a category is regular if it has images, it is cartesian and covers are stable under pullback. He further proves that a cover is the same as a strong epi in a category with pullbacks. On page 20. he says that "morphisms with the property described in 1.3.2.(ii) are sometimes called strong epi or extremal epi; but we shall not need any special name for them, since we shall only consider this property in cartesian categories." Does this mean that they are the same in cartesian categories?

Comment: If you look at his definition of "cover" you will see that it is what everyone else calls "extremal epimorphism". The only hypothesis needed is that covers are epimorphisms.

Comment: @ZhenLin right. I missed that. Thanks.